# VBA text formatting centre alignment

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA so apologies for ignorance!

Trying to insert some text from a form [me.CustomerName] into a location in a document [ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmCustName1")]. it works, but resets the text alignment to left when the original text it's replacing is centre aligned

Incorrect Code that's failing:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmCustName1").Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter.Text = Me.CustomerName
```

anyone able to tell me what the right modifier and syntax might be?

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for the code in your question is:

```
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmCustName1").Range
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .Text = Me.CustomerName
End With
```

Whether this will solve your issue will depend on whether the bookmark includes the end of paragraph mark.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. It worked, but I had to reverse the .text and. paragraphformat lines - I guess it was carrying forward formatting from the me.customername variable and was over-writing if ordered the other way around, but working perfectly now!